# LINQ GroupBy Usage

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am using this to get all my records ordered by date:

```
Dim myData = db.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Exercise_Create_Date)
```

I loop through with this:

```
    For Each i As Tbl_Exercise In myData

        data.Add(New Object() {i.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc, i.Exercise_Duration})

    Next
```

How can I group by `i.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc` so I don't have duplicates?

I tried this:

```
Dim myData = db.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID).GroupBy(Function(x) x.Exercise_Type_ID)
```

But, I don't know how to access the variables within my loop.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

```
<EmployeeAuthorize()>
Function ExercisePieChartData() As JsonResult

    ' get current employee's id
    Dim db1 As EmployeeDbContext = New EmployeeDbContext
    Dim user1 = db1.Tbl_Employees.Where(Function(e) e.Employee_EmailAddress = User.Identity.Name).Single()
    Dim empId = user1.Employee_ID

    Dim activityGroups = db.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID = empId).GroupBy(Function(x) x.Exercise_Type_ID)

    Dim data = New List(Of Object)

    ' columns (headers)
    data.Add(New Object() {"Type", "Duration"})

    ' Iterate through each collection of activities, grouped by activity types
    For Each group In activityGroups

        ' Iterate through each Tbl_Exercise in the group
        For Each activity In group

            ' Do something with an individual element
            data.Add(New Object() {activity.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc, activity.Exercise_Duration})

        Next

    Next

    Return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

End Function
```

**Edit:**

```
    ' Iterate through each collection of activities, grouped by activity types
    For Each group In activityGroups

        Dim type = ""
        Dim duration = 0

        ' Iterate through each Tbl_Exercise in the group
        For Each activity In group

            ' Do something with an individual element
            type = activity.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc
            duration += activity.Exercise_Duration

        Next

        data.Add(New Object() {type, duration})

    Next
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused, you say you want to group by `ExType_Desc`, but your example uses `Exercise_Type_ID`, which one are you looking to group by?

Comment: Please notice `ExType_Desc` belongs to `Tbl_Exercise_Type` and is accessed via `i.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc`.

Comment: Just so I understand, for each employee are you trying to get a collection of their exercise durations, grouped by the type of activity they are performing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Your example isn't entirely clear, so I'm going to make a few assumptions about what you are trying to do with my solution.  I'll modify it as needed as more details are made available.

From what it looks like, for each employee you are trying to get a collection of types of exercise that they have performed, and with each type of exercise you would also like a collection of the lengths of time that they spent performing these activities.

I'm going to assume that a row in `Tbl_Exercises` looks like this:

```
Public Class Tbl_Exercise

    Public Property Exercise_Employee_ID As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Type_ID As Integer
    Public Property Exercise_Type_Desc As String
    Public Property Exercise_Duration As Integer

End Class
```

The attempt you make at the end is pretty close, you just need to actually use the grouping once you've created it.

What the `GroupBy` method has returned you here is actually an `IGrouping(Of Integer, Tbl_Exercise)` where the key is the `Exercise_Type_ID` and the value is a collection of rows that are grouped by the key.  To access them its pretty simple, you just have to think of the groupings as a sort of nested collection:

```
    Dim activityGroups = db.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID = employeeId).GroupBy(Function(x) x.Exercise_Type_ID)

    ' Iterate through each collection of activities, grouped by activity types
    For Each group In activityGroups

        ' Iterate through each Tbl_Exercise in the group
        For Each activity In group

            ' Do something with an individual element
            Console.WriteLine(activity.Exercise_Duration)

        Next

    Next
```

Obviously, you may want to do something different than print out individual collections, you may want to data bind each grouping to their own `DataGrid` so that you can display them separately.  You may want to sort each grouping by date, or you may only want the first element from each group.  Once you understand how the groupings are structured, it should be pretty easy to accomplish exactly what you're looking for.

**Edit:**

If you're just looking to aggregate some field in the grouping, this is very simple to accomplish without needing to resort to looping over the results.  Simply adding a call to `Select` on top of your `GroupBy` will let you project the results into your desired aggregate form:

```
Dim data = db.Tbl_Exercises _
                .Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID = empId) _
                .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Exercise_Type_Desc) _
                .Select(Function(x)
                            Return New With {
                                ' x.Key will give you access to the value that the grouping is grouped by
                                .Exercise_Type_Desc = x.Key,
                                .TotalDuration = x.Sum(Function(y) y.Exercise_Duration)
                            }
                        End Function)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this on Monday.  The answer I was looking for seems to be in the part where you have to loop through the groups.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect.  The items in `activity.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc` are still listed in duplicate, they don't seem to be grouped.  I edited my question with my whole action.

Comment: This is an example of what it is doing http://postimage.org/image/ejuh6jeex/.  I changed my query to `Dim activityGroups = db.Tbl_Exercises.Where(Function(x) x.Exercise_Employee_ID = empId).GroupBy(Function(x) x.Tbl_Exercise_Type.ExType_Desc)` but this is what it does.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I changed my code one last time and it works properly now, but my method creates local variables and may not be the most efficient.  I was hoping to accomplish this by using the `groupby` in a lambda.

Comment: @user1477388 Added an example that sums the exercise duration for you in one statement.

Comment: Thanks that looks awesome.  The only problem is I just realized that I need to add a condition that will add all groups into one "other" category after the fourth or fifth group (so I don't have like 10 groups listed).  I know how to do this in my code, but not with your select statement.